# Wrapping a callback-based class to an async one

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, callback

I'm referencing a class that performs various demanding operations using callbacks rather than async operations. For example:

```
class CallbackClass : SomeSdkCallbacks
{
    public void RequestData()
    {
        // We call this to request some data.
        // After some time, this will trigger OnDataReturned to be called
    }

    public void OnDataReturned(DataObject data)
    {
        // This will be called automatically with returned data via SomeSdkCallbacks
    }
}
```

There are many instances of this type of structure throughout this class.

What I'm trying to do is create a wrapper class around this one that simplifies it's usage. The structure that I'm going for at the moment is:

```
class MyWrapperClass
{
    CallbackClass CallbackClass;

    public MyWrapperClass()
    {
        this.CallbackClass = new CallbackClass();
    }

    public DataObject GetData()
    {
        this.CallbackClass.RequestData();

        // Somehow wait until this.CallbackClass.OnDataReturned is called?

        // Somehow get the data that would be passed in to this.CallbackClass.OnDataReturned()???
    }
}
```

What is the best method of wrapping up a 'callback' architecture into a single asynchronous method?

*Edit*: To clarify, ideally I would like to package this up into a single method that can return the data in a single request. See the `MyWrapperClass.GetData()` method in my example for my ideal structure.

*Edit 2*: I'm aware that this desired architecture is bad form. Unfortunately that is the requested structure that has been asked of me.

Comment: Methods starting with `On` (as in `OnDataReturned`) are, by convention, the methods that raise events and not those that handle the events. It seems like your architecture is a bit faulty.

Comment: Also there is nothing in the method `public void OnDataReturned(DataObject data)` that lets you intercept this in any way. It is impossible to do what you ask with the code you've shown. You need to provide us with a [mcve] so we can get a valid solution.

Comment: @Enigmativity Good point, however that method is implementing the `SomeSdkCallbacks` interface, of which I have no control over.

Comment: Unless you have some control over something then this is an impossible question to answer. Please show us what you can and can't control. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Enigmativity You clearly didn't understand my question. But don't worry, Filip understood and answered it.

Comment: My understanding is that you couldn't modify `CallbackClass`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
        class CallbackClass<T>
        {
            private TaskCompletionSource<T> task = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();

            public void RequestData()
            {
               
            }

            public void OnDataReturned(T data)
            {
                task.SetResult(data);
            }

            public Task<T> Task { get { return task.Task; } }
        }

        class MyWrapperClass
        {
            public Task<DataObject> GetData()
            {
                var cls = new CallbackClass<DataObject>();

                cls.RequestData();

                return cls.Task;
            }
        }
```

Just note that `TaskCompletionSource` must be created per operation so you don't use the same one for two different calls. With this you can use the `async` keyword. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/tpl-and-traditional-async-programming) might help a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation you can add some event on CallBackClass.
Like here:

```
class CallbackClass : SomeSdkCallbacks
{
    public event Action<object> DataReturnedEvent;
    public void RequestData()
    {
        // We call this to request some data.
        // After some time, this will trigger OnDataReturned to be called
    }
    public void OnDataReturned(DataObject data)
    {
        DataReturnedEvent?.Invoke(data);
    }
}
```

And you can use the event in the wrapper class

```
class MyWrapperClass
{
    CallbackClass CallbackClass;

    public MyWrapperClass()
    {
        this.CallbackClass = new CallbackClass();
        CallbackClass.DataReturnedEvent =+ ProcessData;
    }
    private void ProcessData(object Data)
    {
        //some data processing
    }
    public DataObject GetData()
    {
        this.CallbackClass.RequestData()               
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem with this is that if you call `MyWrapperClass.GetData()`, the data is not actually returned from that call. Can you think of a way for `GetData()` to request and return the data itself, or would that be bad practice?

Comment: It is the simplest way for reaching your target. Wait just you are getting your data from GetData() method don't have meaning. You don't know when it is happening and waiting freezes current thread. Better way if your system will work after calling GetData() and later the system will react on the event about deliver data. Other way is to use asybc/await pattern, but it more difficult way because you must make the type according EAP pattern (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ms228969(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Else one link about EAP https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/implementing-the-event-based-asynchronous-pattern